# numpy.gaussian_kde: ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

despite my data not containing any infs or nans, I get this error:

```
  File ".\eval.py", line 101, in <module>
    kernel = gaussian_kde(A[idxs][:,0])
  File "F:\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.set_bandwidth(bw_method=bw_method)
  File "F:\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 556, in set_bandwidth
    self._compute_covariance()
  File "F:\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\kde.py", line 568, in _compute_covariance
    self._data_inv_cov = linalg.inv(self._data_covariance)
  File "F:\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py", line 948, in inv
    a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
  File "F:\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 263, in _asarray_validated
    a = toarray(a)
  File "F:\Python\miniconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 485, in asarray_chkfinite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

I've checked for nans and infs but there aren't any:

```
print(np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(A)))   # 0
print(np.count_nonzero(np.isinf(A)))   # 0

kernel = gaussian_kde(A[idxs][:,0])     # error here
```

What should I fix ?

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic the whole code is there basically, A is a np.array with shape [1000,1] and idxs is of shape [497,1].

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I have the same problem: I'm calling ```scipy.stats.gaussian_kde( arr )``` on a NumPy array of positive values, all less that about 1100, with no NANs, and yet I'm getting the error ```ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs```

Comment: Ok, I figured out my problem:  I cannot use an array that is shape (N,1). I have to drop the dimension to make it shape (N,)